# ip addr show find interface name by ip address

Tags: networking

I want to be able to output the interface name being used by an IP address. For example in the output below, I know that the ip address **192.168.248.130** is on the interface **ens33**.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:c6:d1:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    inet 192.168.248.130/24 brd 192.168.248.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 1756sec preferred_lft 1756sec
    inet6 fe80::55bb:a133:fb76:69d9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would want the output to be `192.168.248.130/24 ens33`

Answer (score 3):

The [man page for ip](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) mentions the `-o` and `-br` options for one-line and brief output:

```
$ IP=192.168.120.19
$ ip -br addr show to $IP
wlp113s0         UP             192.168.120.19/24 fe80::a15a:dd9f:8fbf:f1dd/64
```

That's almost what you want. I'd pick `awk` for the rest:

```
$ ip -br addr show to $IP | awk '{print $3,$1}'
192.168.120.19/24 wlp113s0
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is shorter, so I'll add this as a more general approach offering the possibility of compiling arbitrary fields of the `ip` command (or others with JSON output capability) with minor modifications.
So this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run with IP address as first parameter
ip -j address | jq -j --arg IP "$1" '.[].addr_info[] | select(.family == "inet" and .local == ($IP)) | (.local,"/",.prefixlen," ",.label)'
```

The first part `ip -j address` outputs the data in JSON format which is then processed by `jq`. Its `-j` parameter removes the quotes and the newline from the output. Its `--arg IP "$1"` parameter passes the first shell parameter as the internal variable *IP*.

The middle part selects the desired `addr_info` element and the final part (after the last `|`) compiles the output.

Annotations:

- It seems to be necessary to wrap the shell variable in a new variable(here *IP*) for `jq` to accept it.
- The brackets surrounding is variable `($IP)` are necessary, see [a comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027637/1305969))